# Replacing XML elements in SQL server with descending value

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Given an XML variable with these contents:

```
<Root>
    <Parent>
        <ItemID>28</ItemID>
        <Child>
            <ItemID>28</ItemID>
        </Child>
        <Child>
            <ItemID>28</ItemID>
        </Child>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <ItemID>38</ItemID>
        <Child>
            <ItemID>38</ItemID>
        </Child>
    </Parent>
</Root>
```

I need to replace each /Root/Parent/ItemID value with a descending number starting from -1, and then replace each Child/ItemID with the value from it's parent ItemID element.  For example, the XML above should be transformed into this:

```
<Root>
    <Parent>
        <ItemID>-1</ItemID>
        <Child>
            <ItemID>-1</ItemID>
        </Child>
        <Child>
            <ItemID>-1</ItemID>
        </Child>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <ItemID>-2</ItemID>
        <Child>
            <ItemID>-2</ItemID>
        </Child>
    </Parent>
</Root>
```

Easy to do in c#, I'm stumped on getting the syntax right in SQL Server.  Unfortunately I have to do it this way to work with a legacy system.

Comment: Do you need all child items to be the same as the parent?

Comment: @astander Yes, the child itemID must be the same as the itemID of the parent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XML is not valid so I changed it to what I think you meant.

You can shred the XML, use row_number() to calculate the new ItemID and rebuild it using `for xml path`.

```or-tag-here
declare @XML xml = '
<Root>
    <Parent>
        <ItemID>28</ItemID>
        <Child>
            <ItemID>28</ItemID>
        </Child>
        <Child>
            <ItemID>28</ItemID>
        </Child>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <ItemID>38</ItemID>
        <Child>
            <ItemID>38</ItemID>
        </Child>
    </Parent>
</Root>'

select P.ItemID,
       (
       select P.ItemID
       from P.Child.nodes('Child') as C(N)
       for xml path('Child'), type
       )
from
  (
  select -row_number() over(order by P.N) as ItemID,
         P.N.query('Child') as Child
  from @XML.nodes('/Root/Parent') as P(N)
  ) as P
for xml path('Parent'), root('Root'), type
```

Comment: Thanks!  That looks great, you were correct that the XML was invalid - fixed the question up.  My actual XML is a little more complicated, but once I've checked this works I will accept.

Answer (score 1):

Mikael's solution was elegant but in reality my XML was a bit more complicated than in the question (many more elements, some attributes, etc), so recreating the XML became more complicated and a bit of a maintenance issue.  So in the end I solved the problem with some good old procedural code:

```
declare @XML xml = '<Root>
    <Parent>
        <ItemID>28</ItemID>
        <Child>
            <ItemID>28</ItemID>
        </Child>
        <Child>
            <ItemID>28</ItemID>
        </Child>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <ItemID>18</ItemID>
        <Child>
            <ItemID>18</ItemID>
        </Child>
    </Parent>
</Root>'

DECLARE @CountOfParent INT = @XML.value('count(/Root/Parent)', 'int') 
WHILE @CountOfParent > 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @CountOfParent
    --Replace the current Parent/ItemID element with -@CountOfParent
    SET @XML.modify('replace value of (/Root/Parent/ItemID/text())[sql:variable("@CountOfParent")][1] with -sql:variable("@CountOfParent")')

    --Now loop through all of THIS elements <Child> elements, also setting the ItemID to -@CountOfParent
    DECLARE @CountOfChildren INT = @XML.value('count(/Root/Parent[sql:variable("@CountOfParent")]/Child)', 'int') 
    WHILE @CountOfChildren > 0
    BEGIN
        set @XML.modify('replace value of (/Root/Parent[sql:variable("@CountOfParent")]/Child[sql:variable("@CountOfChildren")]/ItemID/text())[1] with -sql:variable("@CountOfParent")')
        set @CountOfChildren = @CountOfChildren - 1
    END
    SET @CountOfParent = @CountOfParent - 1
END

SELECT @XML
```

However, as Mikael answered the question, I have accepted his answer and am just including this for reference.